# Moving data generated by a Google form from the response tab to another tab

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to copy data from a Google Sheets tab linked to a Google form into a new tab. I used the function  `='Form Responses 1'!B2`, then copied the formula in the other cells of the column. But when I submit a new form, the formula in the destination cell automatically skips a row. So instead of the next row getting data from the next cell in the column from the responses tab, nothing moves over and the formula is changed to `='Form Responses 1'!B4` instead of the formula  `='Form Responses 1'!B3`, which it was prior to me submitting the form.

What am I doing wrong?